# Why would I want to use a font loader with Webpack & React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webfont-loader

I don't quite understand why I would need a font loader in my React App, using Webpack, but I see many tutorials around this. Can I not just include the font in my CSS, as usual, and then have it available in React?

Or am I simply wrong in the assumption that I do need a font loader? If I am, why are people using one?

Comment: The webpack documentation on font loading answers this in the very first paragraph.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot find what you are referring to though.